# Daily Feed a SQL server table from a CSV file in sFTP

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ftp, etl

I have a CSV file that can be acessed only via sFTP. 
The CSV file is daily updated (same structure but different values).

My aim is to daily copy the values of the CSV and paste it into a SQL Server table. Of course the process needs to be automated.

My CSV also contains too many row. The first column of the csv is 'ID'. And I have a fixed list of 'ID'. So I need to do some filtering before to paste into SQL Server

What would be the best option to reach the aim? Using an external ETL, Batch, PowerShell, SQL Script ?

Answer (score 0):

Integration services (SSIS) is a good choice, because you can use a combinition of tasks  (FTP connection, flat file source, t-SQL, ....), and you can integrate an SSIS package in SQL Server job to be executed daily.